# transforming a list of lists of data into a matrix in python (check inside)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I'm writing code that transforms a list of lists into a matrix. This function should be scalable to larger lists, the input i have is just to make the problem easier to tackle. I'm still a beginner so I need a little bit of help =)

-input:
In the example input, list1 is a dataset of fruit and color pairs:

```
list1 = [[["apple", "red"], " 1 "],[["apple", "yellow"], " 1 "], [["apple", "green"], " 1 "]]
list1 += [[["lemon", "red"], " 0 "], [["lemon", "yellow"], " 1 "], [["lemon", "green"], " 0 "]]
list1 += [[["pear ", "red"], " 0 "], [["pear", "yellow"], " 0 "], [["pear", "green"], " 1 "]]
```

-Desired output:

```
['', 'apple', 'lemon', 'pear']
['red', ' 1 ', 0, 0]
['yellow', 0, ' 1 ', 0]
['green', 1, 0, ' 1 ']
```

-My output

```
['///', 'apple', 'lemon', 'pear']
['red', ' 1 ', 0, 0]
['yellow', 0, ' 1 ', 0]
['green', 0, 0, ' 0 ']
```

------My attempt:-----

```
# create empty matrix
matrix=[]
for row in range(4):
    new_row =[]
    for col in  range(4):
        new_row.append(0)   #if starting    all-0
    matrix.append(new_row)

    # add object names
    names = ["///", "apple", "lemon", "pear"]
    color = ["///", "red", "yellow", "green"]
    color = color[::-1]
    matrix[0] = names
    for row in matrix:
        row[0] = color.pop()

    second_obj = 0
    for row in range(4):
        for col in range(4):
            if list[row][0][0] == matrix[0][col]:
                while list[row][0][1] != matrix[second_obj][0]:
                    second_obj += 1
                else:
                    if matrix[row][row] != "///":
                        matrix[row][row] = list[row][1] 
                    second_obj = 0
```

Comment: Try numpy, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a manual loop to search through a list is overcomplicating things. Writing two loops to search through two lists of strings and trying to intermingle them while also looping over indexing something else… it's no wonder you confused yourself.

Let's scrap that, and instead use some dictionaries:

```
columns = {'apple': 1, 'lemon': 2, 'pear': 3}
rows = {'red': 1, 'yellow': 2, 'green': 3}
```

Now, if you want to know which matrix element to put something in, there's no loops, just two dict lookups:

```
>>> (colname, rowname), value = [["apple", "red"], " 1 "]
>>> columns[colname]
1
>>> rows[rowname]
1
```

So, now all we have to do is start with an empty matrix:

```
matrix = [
    ['///', 'apple', 'lemon', 'pear'],
    ['red', 0, 0, 0],
    ['yellow', 0, 0, 0],
    ['green', 0, 0, 0]]
```

… loop over the elements:

```
for (colname, rowname), value in list1:
```

… look up the column and row:

```
    col = columns[colname]
    row = rows[rowname]
```

… and store the number:

```
    matrix[row][col] = value
```

That's all there is to it.

Well, almost. You have a problem in your data, where one of the strings is `'pear '`, instead of `'pear`'. If that's a bug in the data, you can just fix that. If your code is supposed to handle that, you have to decide how to handle it. One obvious option is to just strip off any excess whitespace from the strings:

```
    col = columns[colname.strip()]
    row = rows[rowname.strip()]
```

---

What if you don't know all the labels in advance, and need to find them programmatically?

You could just an extra pass over the list before the main one, pulling out all of the unique row and column names. For example:

```
rows, columns = {}, {}
for (colname, rowname), value in list1:
    if rowname not in rows:
        next_unused_index = len(rows) + 1
        rows[rowname] = next_unused_index
    if colname not in columns:
        next_unused_index = len(columns) + 1
        columns[colname] = next_unused_index
```

Now, to build the matrix, you need to build it from those two dicts. If you're on Python 3.7, you can rely on the fact that the dicts are in the right order, but it's probably clearer to not depend on that. Let's just build an empty matrix first:

```
matrix = [[0 for _ in range(len(columns)+1)] 
          for _ in range(len(rows)+1)]
```

… then fill in the headers:

```
matrix[0][0] = '///'
for rowname, row in rows.items():
    matrix[row][0] = rowname
for colname, column in columns.items():
    matrix[0][column] = colname
```

… and then you can run the same code as before to fill in the values.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver! Do you know of a way I could transform the list I had into the same style of dictionary? I'm actually doing this on a huge dataset so I can't do it manually.

Comment: @oryx Updated the answer.